# How to use SQLite 3 type affinity?

Tags: sqlite

[SQLite 3 documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) states "type affinity" enforces column data types. But how to turn it on?

Comment: STRICT tables were added in 2021 that could change the game in this regard, see my answer for details and an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type affinity does not force column data types - it simply makes a suggestion as to how the underlying storage engine stores the data.

Under the "type affinity" section:

> The type affinity of a column is the recommended type for data stored
>   in that column. The important idea here is that the type is
>   recommended, not required. **Any column can still store any type of data.**

*(emphasis added)*

As far as "how to turn it on," there's no such thing. This is how SQLite works all the time. There's nothing to turn on or off in order to get this functionality.

Comment: Since 2021, Sqlite developers gave in and implemented strict tables.

Answer (score 2):

The column data types are not enforced, just *suggested* by their declared types in the `create table` statement. This is what they mean by *type affinity*.

> The type affinity of a column is the recommended type for data stored in that column. The important idea here is that the type is recommended, not required. Any column can still store any type of data. It is just that some columns, given the choice, will prefer to use one storage class over another. The preferred storage class for a column is called its "affinity".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force a column to be restricted to a specific type, you
can switch to [*STRICT tables*](https://www.sqlite.org/stricttables.html),
a feature added with version 3.37.0 (2021-11-27).

When this mode is enabled, you are limited to INT, INTEGER, REAL, TEXT,
BLOB, and ANY types. You will also notice that the magic extraction of a
type name (alias) in your declaration (treating `unrealistic` as `REAL`)
is disabled.

Let's show this with an example in the command line shell for SQLite.

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.42.0 2023-05-16 12:36:15
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> CREATE TABLE screen_pos (x INT, y INTEGER) STRICT;
```

(Note how the names `INT` and `INTEGER` are preserved while they
represent the same type.)

The following queries work as usual, since the transformation of the
input arguments into integers is valid:

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO screen_pos VALUES (1, 2);
sqlite> INSERT INTO screen_pos VALUES ('3', '4');
sqlite> INSERT INTO screen_pos VALUES (5.0, 6.0);
```

Attempts to insert values that cannot be converted to integers are rejected:

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO screen_pos VALUES (1, 2.1);
Runtime error: cannot store REAL value in INTEGER column screen_pos.y (19)

sqlite> INSERT INTO screen_pos VALUES ('3', 'four');
Runtime error: cannot store TEXT value in INTEGER column screen_pos.y (19)

sqlite> INSERT INTO screen_pos VALUES ('5.1', 6);
Runtime error: cannot store REAL value in INT column screen_pos.x (19)
```

In the table, we still have the following data stored:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM screen_pos;
x  y
-  -
1  2
3  4
5  6
```